# Error using the Boto Library to upload files

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I am using the `boto` library in Python to upload few files to my Amazon Cloud Bucket. If the file size is very less than 100kb, upload is successful.

If I try to upload an job file which is over 700kB, it often fails, with an error message ,

> error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host

Any idea, what could be the issue here,

Here is the code snippet, I am using to upload the files :

```
conn = S3Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
#print "connection made"

b = conn.get_bucket(BUCKET)
#print "Gotten reference to bucket named " + BUCKET

#uploadfile = sys.argv[1]
print "Uploading The File : " + uploadfile

k = Key(b)
k.key = KEY

k.set_contents_from_filename(uploadfile, policy='public-read')
#print "Uploaded file"
k.make_public()
```

Comment: If it is happening randomly, it is likely a network-related issue. If you have random network issues, it is more likely to affect larger file uploads. Does it work successfully if you copy files using the AWS Command-Line Interface (`aws s3 cp` command)? The CLI uses boto underneath.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that it was a network related issue. I cannot pinpoint what the issue is/was now. But after few hours, I was able to upload the files.